# Using browser back button to remove modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog, coffeescript, jquery-events

http://morningharwood.com/works clicking on the project button in lower right corner brings up a very basic modal.  When testing on I noticed that the back button does not remove the modal.  How do I make sure that the browser back button will remove the modal window?

[Heres the full Gist](https://gist.github.com/matthewharwood/6237927)

```
enter = $(".enter")
createModal = () ->
  $(".modal-bg").removeClass("animated fadeInUpBig").addClass "on animated fadeInUpBig"



$(enter).on "click", (event) ->
  createModal()
```

HTML

```
<a class="enter" href="#">View Project<span></span></a>
```

SCSS

```
  modal-bg{
    background:#fff;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    z-index: 101;
    display:none;
    visibility:hidden;
    height:1px;

    &.on 
        {
            display: block !important;
            visibility: visible !important;
            height:100%;
            top:0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//close modals with back btn
$('.modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    window.history.pushState('forward', null, '#modal');
});

$('.modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    //pop the forward state to go back to original state before pushing the "Modal!" button
});

$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```

This works. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Use the  [jquery unLoad event](http://api.jquery.com/unload/)
Then in your callback remove the modal

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
    removeModal()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be just to add something after the `hash-tag`

```
 <a class="enter" href="#project-modal">View Project<span></span></a>
```

and afterwards you can just hook to a jQuery event like this:

```
 $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
   //... do some stuff here ...  
 });
```